# Deleting refs from nested table Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete, nested-table

I've got this tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Cuenta_udt;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE cuentas_array AS TABLE OF REF Cuenta_udt;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Cliente_udt AS OBJECT (
    DNI         VARCHAR(9),
    Telefono    NUMBER,
    Direccion   VARCHAR(100),
    Email       VARCHAR(50),
    Edad        NUMBER,
    Apellidos   VARCHAR(40),
    Nombre      VARCHAR(30),
    Cuentas     cuentas_array) FINAL;
/

CREATE TABLE Cliente OF Cliente_udt(
    DNI         PRIMARY KEY,
    Telefono    NOT NULL,
    Direccion   NOT NULL,
    Edad        NOT NULL,
    Apellidos   NOT NULL,
    Nombre      NOT NULL
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED NESTED TABLE Cuentas STORE AS Cuentas_tab;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE clientes_array AS TABLE OF REF Cliente_udt;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Cuenta_udt AS OBJECT (
    IBAN               VARCHAR(28),
    Saldo              FLOAT,
    Numero_de_cuenta   NUMBER,
    Fecha_creacion     DATE,
    Clientes           clientes_array ) NOT INSTANTIABLE NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE TABLE Cuenta OF Cuenta_udt (
    IBAN                        PRIMARY KEY,
    Saldo                       NOT NULL,
    Numero_de_cuenta            NOT NULL,
    Fecha_creacion              NOT NULL
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED NESTED TABLE Clientes STORE AS Clientes_tab;
```

I'd like to define a trigger which fires every time I delete a row in Cliente and which deletes all dangling references in Clientes nested table in every Cuenta row, but I've no idea about how could I achieve that.

Comment: look at cascading delete https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: It's not a foreign key, it's a ref data type nested table